# Substitute for 455 kHz Ceramic filters in new designs

Tags: filter, radio, receiver, superheterodyne

I was wondering what has ever happened with the 455 kHz ceramic filters commonly used in the second IF stage of a superhet radio receivers?

All but just a very few (and those left over don't seem to stock them anyway) don't manufacture anymore and are marked as discontinued.
Murata, AVX etc used to have them and there is some stock left about with the standard distributors, but now obviously marked as NRND and obsolete.

For a new design I would require as much as possible off-the-shelf parts so my immediate search was for this 455 kHz component thinking it would be easy to find. This is the case for the 45 MHz first IF stage crystal filters which seem to be a lot more common (eg Goledge), but not the case for these formerly readily available parts anymore.

Anyway, other alternatives such as active filters is always an option. But in the meantime,

- somebody might shed some light on the gradual disappearance of these formerly standard components?
- Anybody knows why other than "no demand" perhaps, given there are stil many radio chip-sets that call for this second IF stage?
- Or is there an alternative more commonly used that has superseeded
  this ceramic filter?

Comment: Digital signal processing means you can easily filter without an IF stage and down convert straight to baseband.

Comment: hi yes that's obvious silly me ... after further perusal of the chip-set datasheet it would appear the option is there for the 455 KHz filter(s) but depending on the modem used following the receiver, simply using the I/Q outputs of the final down-conversion stage should suffice. So no need for these ceramic filters afterall ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have two alternatives:

1) Go forwards : as Marcus says, use a decent low pass filter (or analog bandpass filter if undersampling), sample in a fast ADC, and implement the required bandpass in DSP or FPGA.

2) Go backwards : study IF circuits that pre-date ceramic filters. These were generally multi-stage LC filters, based around IFTs where the secondary winding controlled the coupling between tuned circuits. Nobody can stop you winding your own inductors...

Comment: As a representative of the Global SDR Enforcement Agency, I'm afraid I'll have to confiscate these unauthorized inductors. Go ahead, use the ADC. Inductance is futile.

Comment: @user253751 As a member of the Reactance, I will have to disagree.

Comment: as mentioned in my comment above the confusion arises from the option of either using the final down-conversion outputs for low IF output filtering, or for I/Q demodulation. Since it's the later that will be used (still have to find a suitable demodulator) there is no issue any more, so thanks for the reminder of the purpose of DSPs and how much they can gut component manufacturers ;-)That's a relief but nevertheless the relatively sudden obsolescence of these once common components kind of scared the s**t out of me …

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at an all-in-one AM-FM-SW-LW [radio IC](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4730-31-34-35-D60.pdf) and the surrounding components:

[image]

The only frequency determining component is a single 32.768kHz watch crystal.

You might want to look at SDR (Software Defined Radio) circuits.

Alternatively, it's quite practical these days to make active filters in the 0.5MHz range using op-amps. Your Q is not going to be very high if you have audio type bandwidths.

Answer (score 2):

> somebody might shed some light on the gradual disappearance of these formerly standard components?

as you noticed, demand and supply. Putting something on a 400-something kHz IF requires that signal to have a bandwidth much smaller than 400 kHz – that's become pretty rare for communication signals. Even for broadcast FM, that's not an overly useful IF, as 75 kHz (which is roughly a sensible upper boundary for deviation) isn't orders of magnitude smaller.

> Anybody knows why other than "no demand" perhaps, given there are stil many radio chip-sets that call for this second IF stage?

Um, you're probably from an amateur radio background, right?

No, there aren't many radio chipsets that call for a second IF stage.

Why would they? A single IF at say a couple MHz where there's good filters is totally sufficient these days; amplifiers and ADCs have gone a long way, so it's much harder to drive them into nonlinearity (the "there's a blocker" scare is, I swear, a very ham thing to have, and it's very rarely based on physical facts). So, lax analog filtering, then conversion to digital, then filtering in digital domain. Replace the second LO and mixer (expensive!) with subsampling (cheap).

Filtering a signal with a bandwidth smaller than 1 MHz (which is the absolute maximum that an IF of 500 kHz or less would allow for) in digital domain is what we call trivial, and quite power efficient. So, we do that. Digital filters are easier, and usually way better, than even very expensive analog ones.

Consequently, we, by far, prefer significantly higher IFs than 455 kHz (that's baseband, really). If you happen to build a radio that is supposed to work with HF/SW/LW transmissions, you'll often mix **up** to a more sensible IF (and that's the only case where I've seen dual-stage IF superhets outside of measurement and signal surveillance applications, and it's certainly the only high-volume one).

> Or is there an alternative more commonly used that has superseeded this ceramic filter?

Digital filtering, and higher-bandwidth signalling, and conversion.

Comment: thanks Marcus, the chipset I was referring to, after some further reading in the fine print, does in fact provide for this very option, besides also the I/Q outputs which are also readily available after final IF down-conversion, so it was perhaps with too much, and unnecessary haste that I sought an explanation for the disappearance of these once common components. Thinking like we've been robbed or something ;-)

Comment: The modem chipset(s) following the receiver should incorporate all the A/D conversion and subsequent digital filtering as you well pointed out !! Thank god for chipsets and that they do all this for us these days ! I was seriously not looking forward to have to allocate extra signal processing resources for such a silly thing, when the rest of the existing noise cancellation, audio compression and multi-channel TMDA synchronisation already takes allot of CPU time, not to mention having to find 2 extra DMA channels for this would be a pain ..... thanks for clarification !

Comment: Otherwise … we'll have to disagree on the usefulness of narrowband channels nowadays as you point out, as we do all existing voice-com in 50 KHz channels, and we think, and our clients think, that is very useful after all ;-)

Comment: To add to what Marcus said, the name of the game nowadays is to go digital as soon as you can.  With 12-bit ADCs capable of converting at >1 GSa/sec available, there is no need in many applications to down-convert to a frequency less than ~500 MHz.  Planning how to get to that 500 MHz frequency for sampling is something receiver folks spend lots of time pondering.  In many cases, it's advantageous to up-convert say, from 10 GHz to 31 GHz, and then down to 500 MHz.  It's all about managing spurs and nth order mixing products.

Comment: I'd love to have the time to do all that and to go digital and to find 2 extra DMA channels and then to have to re-route the BGA to accomodate the re-configured I2S ports all for that extra digital filter. Sometimes it seems like having a simple 4-pole ceramic filter in an SMT case to just bang-in with some matching, wasn't so bad afterall in the days of the cosmic microwave backround era ;-)

Comment: @citizen all the audio FM and AM frontend chips I can think of basically give you the fully processed output, i.e. digitized, frequency-corrected, filtered, deemphasized. Those are chips < 1€. You really just need a cheap microcontroller with an I2S rx integrated.

Comment: @citizen [Silabs Si473x series, e.g. this](https://www.silabs.com/audio-and-radio/multiband-radios/si4730-31-radio-receivers) pricing really depends on volume.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to keep in mind.  The 455 KHz IF frequency "standard" came about in the 30's, IIRC.  455 KHz IF filters were implemented with fixed LC circuits, with some adjustments provided, usually through a set screw, to adjust the filter's resonance to allow for manufacturing tolerance and aging affects.

I do not know when ceramic 455 KHz filters came into wide use, but it was well after I got my Lafayette short wave radio in the late 60's.

So if you're looking for an alternative to the ceramic filters, find an old short wave set, or even an old AM radio receiver and cannibalize it.  Of course, these IF filters, because of differences in packaging, would not be a drop in for your ceramic filter.